# Eliminar un objeto dentro de un array

Tags: javascript, json, array, nodejs, objeto

Desde hace algunos días tengo este problema ay no encuentro una solución valida.

Tengo el siguiente array:

```
[
    {
        "id": "12345",
        "email": "pepito@gmail.com",
        "codigoProducto": "[{\"id\":\"9811\",\"quantity\":1,\"seller\":\"1\"},{\"id\":\"981004\",\"quantity\":1,\"seller\":\"1\"},{\"id\":\"1161\",\"quantity\":1,\"seller\":\"1\"},{\"id\":\"1220\",\"quantity\":1,\"seller\":\"1\"},{\"id\":\"520468\",\"quantity\":1,\"seller\":\"1\"},{\"id\":\"215766\",\"quhttps://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/ask#antity\":1,\"seller\":\"1\"},{\"id\":\"738237\",\"quantity\":1,\"seller\":\"1\"},{\"id\":\"5982\",\"quantity\":1,\"seller\":\"1\"},{\"id\":\"199000\",\"quantity\":1,\"seller\":\"1\"},{\"id\":\"125407\",\"quantity\":1,\"seller\":\"1\"}]"
    }
]
```

Como podría eliminar uno de los objetos del array "codigoProducto", por ejemplo como elimino el que tiene él id 9811

---

Como me lo sugirieron lo hice, pero cuando intento agrandar el array no logro conseguirlo, podría darme una mano por favor. Si quisiera este array de más posiciones ¿cómo lo haría?.

```
[ { "id": "12345", "email": "pepito@g.com", "codigoProducto": "[{\"id\":\"9811\",\"quantity\":1,\"seller\":\"1\"},{\"id\":\"981004\",\"quantity\":1,\"seller\":\"1\"}]" }, { "id": "3245", "email": "j@h.com", "codigoProducto": "[{\"id\":\"624649\",\"quantity\":1,\"seller\":\"1\"},{\"id\":\"9811\",\"quantity\":2,\"seller\":\"1\"}]" } ]
```

Comment: Saludos chicos, para quienes estén buscando solución a este problema les comparto otra pregunta donde esta mejor planteado y con una  solución también válida a la necesidad. Agradezco a los que me ayudaron: https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/352304/eliminar-un-recurso-de-un-array-u-objeto-json-con-js Despues de mirar varias opciones pude encontrar la solución adecuada.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

[Filter](https://developer.mozilla.org/es/docs/Web/JavaScript/Referencia/Objetos_globales/Array/filter) podria ser una aproximacion. Esto en combinacion con [JSON.parse()](https://developer.mozilla.org/es/docs/Web/JavaScript/Referencia/Objetos_globales/JSON/parse) ya que la propiedad `codigoProducto` contiene una cadena de texto y no un arreglo como tal.

```js
var idEliminar = '9811'

var datos = [
    {
        "id": "12345",
        "email": "pepito@gmail.com",
       "codigoProducto": "[{\"id\":\"9811\",\"quantity\":1,\"seller\":\"1\"},{\"id\":\"981004\",\"quantity\":1,\"seller\":\"1\"},{\"id\":\"1161\",\"quantity\":1,\"seller\":\"1\"},{\"id\":\"1220\",\"quantity\":1,\"seller\":\"1\"},{\"id\":\"520468\",\"quantity\":1,\"seller\":\"1\"},{\"id\":\"215766\",\"quhttps://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/ask#antity\":1,\"seller\":\"1\"},{\"id\":\"738237\",\"quantity\":1,\"seller\":\"1\"},{\"id\":\"5982\",\"quantity\":1,\"seller\":\"1\"},{\"id\":\"199000\",\"quantity\":1,\"seller\":\"1\"},{\"id\":\"125407\",\"quantity\":1,\"seller\":\"1\"}]"
    }
]

datos[0].codigoProducto = JSON.parse(datos[0].codigoProducto)

datos[0].codigoProducto = datos[0]
                            .codigoProducto
                            .filter(producto=> idEliminar != producto.id)

console.log(datos[0].codigoProducto)
```

Comment: Buena aproximación.

Comment: Hola, puedes agregar eso al final de tu pregunta. Es más claro que en el comentario. Hay un link que dice editar.

Comment: No te preocupes. No es un botón, son links, al principio es enredoso verlo. Debe estar abajo de tus etiquetas.

Answer (score 1):

debes encontrar el index en caso de que no lo tengas, y con la función splice.

```js
var Datos = [ 
  {
    "id": 12345,
    "email": "pepito@g.com",
    "codigoProducto": "[{\"id\":\"9811\",\"quantity\":1,\"seller\":\"1\"},{\"id\":\"981004\",\"quantity\":1,\"seller\":\"1\"}]"
  },
  {
    "id": 3245,
    "email": "j@h.com",
    "codigoProducto": "[{\"id\":\"624649\",\"quantity\":1,\"seller\":\"1\"},{\"id\":\"9811\",\"quantity\":2,\"seller\":\"1\"}]" 
  } 
];
var idx = Datos.findIndex((e) => e.id === 12345);
if(idx != -1){ //Cuando no encuentra el id, te mandara un -1
    Datos.splice(idx, 1);
}
console.log(Datos);
```

Comment: unicamente modifique los tipos de datos, en tu json, si requieres validar por string, tanto en el json como en el find index, lo agregas con "

Comment: Bienvenido a [es.so] te recomiendo hacer el [tour] , en cuanto a tu respuesta es muy buena pero ten cuidado cuando no venga nada, puedes validar eso?

Comment: Eduardo gracia spor tu repsuesta, pero necesito es borrar uno de los objetos que estan dentro del codigoProducto, es decir solo el que tiene el ide 9811. POdrias ayudarme por favor.