# Eliminar un recurso de un array u objeto JSON con JS

Tags: javascript, array, nodejs, objeto

agradecería su ayuda con el siguiente problema.

Tengo el siguiente código:

```js
let codigosPermitidos = [1020,1030,1040,1050,1060];

let miLista = [
   {
  "id":"232323",
  "email":"aoytt@gmail.com",
  "skus":"[{\"id\":\"9811\",\"quantity\":1,\"seller\":\"1\"},{\"id\":\"1020\",\"quantity\":1,\"seller\":\"1\"},{\"id\":\"1161\",\"quantity\":1,\"seller\":\"1\"}]"
   },
   {
  "id":"00122",
  "email":"jsas@hotmail.com",
  "skus":"[{\"id\":\"1060\",\"quantity\":1,\"seller\":\"1\"},{\"id\":\"211795\",\"quantity\":1,\"seller\":\"1\"},{\"id\":\"133426\",\"quantity\":2,\"seller\":\"1\"}]"
   }
]
```

Como podría verificar dentro del objeto "miLista" especificamente dentro de "codigos", si uno de los codigos de "codigosPermitidos" esta incluido y borrar solo el objeto con ese id?

Por ejemplo mi objeto quedaria asi:

```js
let miLista = [
   {
  "id":"232323",
  "email":"aoytt@gmail.com",
  "skus":"[{\"id\":\"9811\",\"quantity\":1,\"seller\":\"1\"},{\"id\":\"1161\",\"quantity\":1,\"seller\":\"1\"}]"
   },
   {
  "id":"00122",
  "email":"jsas@hotmail.com",
  "skus":"[{\"id\":\"211795\",\"quantity\":1,\"seller\":\"1\"},{\"id\":\"133426\",\"quantity\":2,\"seller\":\"1\"}]"
   }
]
```

ya que el objeto con id 1020(de codigosPermitidos) esta dentro de codigos en mi objeto "miLista".

Muchas gracias

Comment: Ya esta pregunta te la respondieron, [aqui](https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/352159/eliminar-un-objeto-dentro-de-un-array), por favor no dupliques preguntas. Si la respuesta no la entiendes puedes pedir aclaración a quien respondió, aunque la respuesta recibida en la pregunta anterior es bastante completa. Saludos

Comment: ¿Responde esto a tu pregunta? [Eliminar un objeto dentro de un array](https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/352159/eliminar-un-objeto-dentro-de-un-array)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Puedes hacer lo siguiente, *mapear* tu lista, el `JSON.parse()` es para transformar a un objeto los skus ya que vienen como string.

Ya que se tiene eso *parseado* tienes que filtrar esa lista de `skus`, como `codigosPermitidos` es un arreglo puedes usar `.includes()` que returna un `true/false` dependiendo de si lo que le pasas se encuentra o no en el arreglo.

Ademas como los codigos en `codigosPermitidos` son numeros se tiene que cambiar el `sku.id` a un numero con `Number()`.

Ya al final se asigna ese listado filtrado a la propiedad `skus` de `miLista`.

```
const nuevaLista = miLista.map(item => {
  const parsed = JSON.parse(item.skus)

  const filtered  = parsed.filter(sku => !codigosPermitidos.includes(Number(sku.id)))

  i.skus = filtered

  return i
})
```

Se podria hacer todo eso en menos lineas, pero creo que es mas dificil de leer a primera vista:

```
const nuevaLista = miLista.map(i => {
  i.skus = JSON.parse(i.skus).filter(sku => !codigosPermitidos.includes(Number(sku.id)))

  return i
})
```

Comment: Issac muchas gracias, sos un mago. Pero probe la primera forma y me aparece un error, y en la segunda cuando trato de hacer console.log(nuevaLista), obtengo este resultado en los sku: [
  { id: '232323', email: 'aoytt@gmail.com', skus: [ [Object] ] },
  {
    id: '00122',
    email: 'jsas@hotmail.com',
    skus: [ [Object], [Object] ]
  }
] - Depronto  podrias ayudarme para que en vez de que me aparezca [Object ] aparezca la info que es e indicarme a que se debe, te lo agradecería mucho.]

Comment: te muestra el `[Obect]` ya que son objetos y al hacer `console.log` esta _imprimiendo_ una represtacion de esos objetos. Lo que podrias hacer es esto: `JSON.stringify(nuevaLista)` y te convertira la lista a un string y si quieres el string con mas formato puedes hacer esto otro `JSON.stringify(nuevaLista, null, 2)`

Comment: Muchas pero muchas gracias, era lo que buscaba.