# Metodo para eliminar valor de propiedad de un objeto Javascript

Tags: javascript, javascript-objeto

Tengo un objeto que contiene un array de objetos, con un método que al llamarlo y pasarle como parámetro un valor de una propiedad de uno de los objetos que contiene, debe eliminar el objeto completo.

```
const inventory = {
    products: [
      { name: "Tablet", price: 460 },
      { name: "Laptop", price: 780 },
      { name: "Cellphone", price: 520 },
    ],
    
    removeProduct(productName) {
    const productIndex = this.products.indexOf(productName);

    if (productIndex === -1) {
      return `Product ${productName} is not in inventory!`;
    }

    this.products.splice(productIndex, 1);
  }
}
```

Al pasarle el nombre de uno de los productos me devuelve que no está en el inventario:

```
console.log(inventory.removeProduct("Laptop"));  //Product Laptop is not in inventory!
```

Gracias.

Comment: ¿Responde esto a tu pregunta? [Eliminar un objeto dentro de un array](https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/352159/eliminar-un-objeto-dentro-de-un-array)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Otra alternativa sería usar **`find()`** para buscar el nombre del producto en los valores de tu objeto (explicación en comentarios):

```js
const inventory = {
  products: [
    { name: 'Tablet', price: 460 },
    { name: 'Laptop', price: 780 },
    { name: 'Cellphone', price: 520 },
  ],

  removeProduct(productName) {
    // busco si el "productName" se encuentra en los valores del objeto.
    const productFind = this.products.find(p => p.name === productName);

    if (!productFind) { // si no encuentra...
      return `Product ${productName} is not in inventory!`; // Retorno este mensaje.
    }
    else { // y si encuentra...
      this.products.splice(this.products.indexOf(productFind), 1); // Busco el índice del producto en el array y lo elimino.
      return `El producto [${productName}] se eliminó correctamente.`; // y muestro este mensaje.
    }
  },
};

console.log(inventory.removeProduct("Laptop"));
console.log(inventory.products); // vemos que el objeto que llevaba el valor "Laptop" no está.
```

Comment: Pero ahí haces 2 búsquedas en vez de una `find` y `indexOf`

Answer (score 3):

El código está buscando el nombre del producto en el array de productos como un string, pero necesita buscar en la propiedad name de cada objeto del array.

Para solucionarlo, puedes usar Array.prototype.findIndex()

```js
let inventory = {
  products: [
    { name: "Tablet", price: 460 },
    { name: "Laptop", price: 780 },
    { name: "Cellphone", price: 520 },
  ],

  removeProduct : function(productName) {
    let productIndex = this.products.findIndex(a=>a.name == productName);
    if (productIndex === -1) {
      return `Product ${productName} is not in inventory!`;
    }
    else{
        this.products.splice(productIndex, 1);
       return `Product ${productName} borrado!`;
    }
 }
}


console.log(inventory.removeProduct("Laptop"));
console.log(inventory.products);
```

Answer (score 0):

Lo hice de esta forma y también funciona.

```
const inventory = {
    products: [
      { name: "Tablet", price: 460 },
      { name: "Laptop", price: 780 },
      { name: "Cellphone", price: 520 },
    ],
    
    removeProduct(productName) {    

    for (const product of this.products) {    
        if (product.name === productName){

            this.products.splice(this.products.indexOf(product), 1);    
            return `Product ${productName} removed!`;
        }
    }

    return `Product ${productName} is not in inventory!`;        
    }
}



console.log(inventory.removeProduct("Laptop"));
console.log(inventory.products);
```

Gracias por sus respuestas!

Comment: Recuerda verificar la respuesta que te sirvió dándole al ✔️ para que tu pregunta esté como respondida, saludos.

Comment: No agregues una respuesta que no aporta a las respuestas que te dieron, poniendo solo codigo... :(

Comment: y menos la aceptes, porque en realidad las respuestas que te sirvieron y contestan la pregunta son las otras... esta es solo tu punto de vista...